# jQuery.each() - passing extra argument to the callback parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a fragment of a plugin that I'm using on my site:

```
$.fn.extend({
    limiter: function(limit, elem) {
        $(this).on("keyup focus", function() {
            setCount(this, elem);
        });
        function setCount(src, elem) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

The `setCount()` function works well only if the `elem` property in **not** an array - only single values are accepted.

I'd like to change it so that I can pass arrays (multiple selection in my case) to the `setCount()` function.

I thought that a solution would be to use `jQuery.each()` iterator like so:

```
$.fn.extend({
    limiter: function(limit, elem) {
        $(this).on("keyup focus", function() {
            $.each(elem, setCount)
        });
        function setCount(src, elem) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that I also have to pass the `this` object which points to the object that received `"keyup focus"` as is the case in the first snippet.

How do I pass `this` object to the callback property of `$.each()` in the given scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding the context, using `bind` (warning not IE8 compatible):

```
$.each(elem, setCount.bind(this))
```

This makes the `this`-context inside each setCount-call, pointing to `this` from the event handler.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep a reference to the "first" `this` and use it in `setCount`:

```
$.fn.extend({
limiter: function(limit, elem) {
    var that = this;

    $(this).on("keyup focus", function() {
        $.each(elem, setCount)
    });
    function setCount(src, elem) {
        // use 'that' here
        ...
    }
}
```

});